# Customize chart in ASP.NET (Microsoft's Chart Controls): how to get x-axis labelling?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, charts

I want to create a chart with Microsoft's Chart Controls, which looks like this Excel chart:
[image: My Excel chart]
Has somebody an idea how to group the elements on the x-axis as on this image?

What I did so far was:

```
            Series s = new Series("Testseries");
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            s.Color = Color.Red;

            s.Points.Add(20,65);
            s.Points.Add(17,66);
            s.Points.Add(17,55);

            Chart1.Series.Add(s);
```

How can I label each data point seperately on the x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem like this:

```
        string[] xval = { "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX", "ElementX" };
        for (int i = 0; i < xval.Length; i++)
        {
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(i + 0.5, i + 1.5, xval[i]);
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels[i].GridTicks = GridTickTypes.TickMark;
        }

        // second label row
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0, 5.5, "Group1", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(5.5, 12.5, "Group2", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(12.5, 21.5, "Group3", 1, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark);
```